# style child element without id using only parent id

Tags: html, css

say you have many html documents and only one css. many of those html documents use many of the same tags. so one has to give each tag an id. is it possible to style spesific tags without id if the "parent" element has an id? if so how do i do this in css.

for ex.
html---

```
// html page a
<table class = 'abc'>
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>

// html page b
<table class = 'def'>
 <tr>
   <td> 2 </td>
```

i can't style with classes for td and th because i use nth-child in css. but if i dont the css for html page b and html page a s css will interfere when i style. in additon im not allowed to inline-style.

is it possible to use say

```
<!-- style td that belongs to page a without styling page b -->
/ some styling code
```

Comment: You mean like a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)? e.g. `.abc td { background: blue }`?

Comment: yes thank you this is what i want, but i cant seem to make it work with nth-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using a simple  .

The   (and yes, that is a space) lets you target all descendants, but, on a similar note, the `>` lets you target direct descendants, but this won't work with tables with descendants of descendants.

So your selector should look something like this:

```css
#id td {
    /* styles here :) */
}
```

If you want to target the nth child, you can use something like this:

```css
#id td:nth-child(3) {
    /* styles here :) */
}
```